# Remove underscore line on a BindingNavigator

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

When I add a BindingNavigator to my forms it has a line that appears under it.  How can I get rid of that line?

[image]

I have looked through all of the settings in the properties but I cannot tell how I can get rid of that line.  I have also looked online and can't find anything, but I cannot be the only person who wants to remove this.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably can't without implementing a subclass and overriding the `OnPaint`, or doing some other hack where you're replacing or modifying the built in rendering.  The problem with this approach is that the BindingNavigator is probably a composite control, meaning there are a bunch of button controls, and a text box control, etc. that all handle a portion of the rendering themselves.  It would be difficult to render the control entirely on your own.

Comment: this is pretty much what I thought.

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating your own renderer where you omit the border from being rendered:

```
public class BorderlessRenderer : ToolStripRenderer {
  protected override void OnRenderToolStripBorder(ToolStripRenderEventArgs e) {
    //base.OnRenderToolStripBorder(e);
  }
}
```

then from code, you can apply it to your navigator:

```
public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
  bindingNavigator1.Renderer = new BorderlessRenderer();  
}
```

Unfortunately, I think this method might hide the separator lines, too.